# Why is force inversely proportional to distance when calculating work?

Tags: forces, energy, work

If W = FD, and W/F = D, that means that as force increases, displacement decreases. I was just having a hard time understanding why thats so. Similarly F = ma and F/m = a, so as (m) increases (a) decreases. That makes sense, since the more the mass the less the acceleration. However, wouldn't it be true that the more the Force the greater the displacement in the Work equation? Just need a proper conceptual explanation. Thanks.

Comment: You nsay more mass less acceleration makes sense for a constant force, why wouldn't more force make less displacement for a constant work?  It's the same idea with different variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep in mind that the amount of work is constant (so you can do the "if I increase this that other thing decreases"). Then, if you increase the force you exert, but the work you do ought to be constant, then you can only move the object so far.

Comment: Ohh, yea I totally forgot about the need of work to be constant for me to think of it this way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly:
   $$
   W=\int \vec{F} \cdot d{\vec \ell} 
   $$
   and only equal to $F\Delta x$ when the force is constant and in the direction of the displacement, which is a special case.  Counterintuitively, you do no work but holding an object in your hands.
2. Secondly, the force is independent of the displacement, and there is no reason why more force should be related to more displacement.  If you let a rock drop, the force is constant but the displacement of the rock is just a matter of the height difference between the final and initial heights.  Gravity is smaller on the Moon than on Earth but that doesn't prevent objects from falling over arbitrary distance on the Earth or on the Moon.

Comment: Thank you, I kind of get it now. However, when thinking about F = ma (F/m = a). As m increases, a decreases.

Comment: Thank you, I kind of get it now. However, when thinking about F = ma   (F/m = a), As (m) increases, (a) decreases. That makes sense because the more the mass of the object the less the acceleration of the object if the force remains the same. So pushing a 50kg boulder with a 1000N force would result in less acceleration than a 5kg boulder with a 1000N force. Similarly, if W = Fd, and W/F = d, so that as (F) increases (d) decreases. However that is a bit counterintuitive. Logically, it makes more sense that as force is increased, the displacement of the object would increase too.